# Flutter and don't know how to solve this errors

Tags: android, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

[image]

[image]

[image]

I wanted images to appear randomly when button is pressed

Comment: don't post images of code, and copy/paste the error message, helpful for OTHER people with the same problem

Answer (score 1):

At the first image, it's just warning and this problem can be solved easily by adding `key` to your contructors

```
class RandomImages extends StatefulWidget {
  const RandomImages({super.key}); // add this
  ...
}
```

For second image, you can pass a `Function` as value of onPressed

```
onPressed: () {
  // onPressed actions
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the key value in proper way

I can correct it for you plz provide me the code as text